# Get the next major version of an npm package (NOT necessarily the latest!)

Tags: bash, npm, package-managers

I'm writing a bash script to update & test packages in bulk. However, I want the script to not jump to the latest version, just the next major version if it exists and pasts test.

I'm looking at something akin to this (longer stretches of code reduced to pseudocode for brevity)

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign package name to $packageName

# START MAIN LOOP

# Start code that does a preliminary test
...
# End code that does preliminary test
# Assign current package version to $current

npm install $packagename@#[next?]
# # The above line is the one I can't figure out. 
# Say, for example, $current is 3.4.7. and 
# $packagename@latest is 5.2.3. This should 
# update to 4.0.0, but if latest is 3.5.8, it would update
# to 3.5.8, but then not update if latest is 3.4.7

# Do post tests
# # If fails post tests
       # alert user to breaking version
       npm install $packagename@$current # revert to previous version

# # If succeeds post tests, check if now at @latest
# # # If not at @latest, repeat MAIN LOOP
# # # If at @latest, exit 0.
```

Comment: @markp-fuso That's not glossing. That key part is the part I don't know how to do. I don't want to identify various schemes, I just want to choose the next major version regardless of scheme since npm supports major/minor versioning.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
arr=('npm' 'yarn' 'puppetter' 'express')
for pkg in "${arr[@]}"; do
    pkg_noinstl=$(npm -g ls "$pkg" | grep -o '(empty)')
    if [[ "$pkg_noinstl" ]]; then
        echo "$pkg: Not Installed"
    else
        myversion=$(npm -g list "$pkg" | grep "@" | cut -d@ -f2)
        int_myversion=$(echo "$myversion" | cut -f3 -d.)
        reg=$(echo "$myversion" | cut -f1,2 -d.)
        newversion=$(npm view "$pkg" versions | grep -oP "$reg.[0-9]{1,2}")
        int_newversion=$(echo "$newversion" | cut -f3 -d. | tail -1)

        if [[ "$int_newversion" -gt "$int_myversion" ]]; then
            n=$(echo "$newversion" | tail -1)
            echo "$pkg:$myversion you have an upgrade-->$n"
        else
            echo "$pkg: OK $myversion"
        fi
    fi
done
```

returns:
[image]

###### if you want +1 release `6.14.8-->6.14.9` then add:

```sh
 next_release=$(((int_myversion + 1)))
 intnr=$(echo "$newversion" | cut -d. -f3 | grep "$next_release")
 n=$(echo "$newversion" | tail -1)
 echo "$pkg:$myversion you have an upgrade-->$n, available-->$reg.$intnr"
```

Comment: there are many things you can replace in the script, for example the array `$arr` you can make it and argument and pass as a `file` of all your programs installed globally. The command for that is  `npm -g ls --depth=0 >installed.txt`, then clean the file